# How to create a matplotlib pie chart with input from a tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pie-chart, text-widget

I want to have a GUI with a tkinter text widget where the user can input values. After hitting the "Create!" button I want the program to open a new window and use the entered values to create a matplotlib pie chart. I tried `get` to get the input and store it in a variable so the program uses it to create the pie chart. But this doesn't work obviously.

As I understood so far I rather have to use an array to get this to work but:

1. I don't know how to save the input as an array for the use of a pie chart.
2. I don't know in which way the input has to be written into the text widget to be able to create an array. With an entry widget one can use `split` to specify that the single values are separated by comma, blank spaces, ... but I haven't found something similar for a text widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def open_pie_chart():
    inputVariable = input_text.get("1.0","end-1c")
    pie_chart_window = tk.Tk()
    frame_pie_chart = tk.Frame(pie_chart_window)
    frame_pie_chart.pack()
    vehicles = ['car', 'bus', 'bicycle', 'motorcycle', 'taxi', 'train']
    fig = plt.Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.pie(inputVariable, radius=1, labels=vehicles)
    chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,frame_pie_chart)
    chart1.get_tk_widget().pack()

root = tk.Tk()

input_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Input")
input_text = tk.Text(input_frame)

create_button = tk.Button(root, command=open_pie_chart, text="Create!")

input_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
input_text.grid(row=1, column=0)
create_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, I'm not sure where you tripped up as in your question you know the right answer (to use `split()`). All you have to do is setup a format that you want the user to use for the input (maybe just separate their values by commas, which is what I use for this example) and then split them on that separator. If you just want spaces, then all you need is `.split()` instead of what I use in the example `.split(',')`. Then, convert those values to `int` and save the new `inputVariable`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = tk.Tk()

def open_pie_chart():
    inputVariable = [int(x) for x in input_text.get(1.0, "end-1c").split(',')]
    pie_chart_window = tk.Tk()
    frame_pie_chart = tk.Frame(pie_chart_window)
    frame_pie_chart.pack()
    vehicles = ['car', 'bus', 'bicycle', 'motorcycle', 'taxi', 'train']
    fig = plt.Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.pie(inputVariable, radius=1, labels=vehicles)
    chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,frame_pie_chart)
    chart1.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
input_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Input, (format = #, #, #, #, #, #)")
input_text = tk.Text(input_frame)

create_button = tk.Button(root, command=open_pie_chart, text="Create!")

input_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
input_text.grid(row=1, column=0)
create_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, this worked perfectly fine! I think my problem before was that I wanted to use `split` directly with the text widget which didn't work. But I was not aware that I could also use `split`  in the form of `inputVariable = [int(x) for x in inputVariable.split(',')]`.

Comment: @Plantz I just realized, you can put it all on one line (check the edit)

Comment: Hey, you're right. This also works. But this proves that one can indeed use `split` in combination with a text widget. I tried it before but received an error like "unexpected command for object" so I thought I can't use it together. Probably I made a mistake when I tried this. But thank you anyway for showing me this.